# What will happen if 2 out of 3 seats are confirmed and 1 seat is in Waitlist which is booked via IRCTC online?

Tags: trains, tickets, indian-railways

I have booked these tickets via the IRCTC website:

```
Sl. No. Name    Age Gender  Status  Coach   Seat / Berth / WL No
1   Ravi        25  Female  CNF     S3      13 
2   Rina        25  Female  CNF     S3      56 
3   Ajay        25  Male    WL      124
```

Since online what will happen if the last ticket is not confirmed, will all tickets be cancelled or only the last?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer by blvdeer is partially correct in that it confirms the rule, but does not answer your question.  The answer to your question is that if there is even one passenger who has a confirmed reservation in a ticket all the passengers in the same ticket can board the train and shall be provided seats as and when they become available.  Partially confirmed tickets will not be automatically dropped.  This is as per the first paragraph of the answer provided by bvldeer

Comment: So would the third passenger have to stand for the entire journey?

Comment: @JonathanReez In case of a long distance train with berths (sleeping bunk beds), the passenger can share berths with other passengers travelling with him. In case of chair cars, well he has to stand. Indian railways e-tickets are automatically cancelled in case of waitlisted passengers, so any such passenger found on train is deemed "ticket-less" and penalised. For partially confirmed e-tickets (as asked by OP) and paper tickets, they are actually allowed to board the train and are not penalised as ticket-less. Such passengers are provided seats as they become free (no-show etc.)

Comment: Any source for that statement? Sounds like a weird rule

Comment: @JonathanReez Well that is what the OP is asking about and the rule has been mentioned in answer by blvdeer. I also modified my original comment to add a long-winding explanation.

Answer (score 8):

[This](https://www.services.irctc.co.in/beta_htmls/Waitlisted_E-Ticket.html) irctc page mentions:

Name of the passengers whose names are partly confirmed/partly waitlist or partly RAC/partly waitlist, their names shall appear in charts including the waitlist passengers.

Names of the Passengers who are left out fully(all the passengers in the transaction) on waiting list after chart preparation,their names will be dropped and will not appear in charts. They are not allowed to board the train. If detected traveling in the train, they shall be treated as passenger traveling without ticket as per extant Railway Rules.Their cancellation shall be done by IRCTC after chart preparation and refund shall be arranged from Railways by IRCTC and credited to customer/Agent account electronically.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you have 2 options:
1) All the passengers can travel and seat will be provided to the waitlist passengers as per the availability.

2) If you do not want to travel without all seats confirmed, you can file a TDR through IRCTC website and TDR can be filed only before 30 minutes of the departure of the train. On successfully filing the TDR, amount will be credited back to your account.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the exact issue where 1 ticket was confirmed and other ticket is in w/l 6 and we were allowed to board the train and berth was allocated based on availability. Hence do not worry if any partial waiting list tickets.

Answer (score -1):

As a general booking rule , if you have a not confirmed pax  in your reservation , all other bookings will be cancelled . 
Anyway I checked the website please see this [link](http://contents.irctc.co.in/en/currentBooking.html) .Then if you do not want to travel without all the reservation confirmed I suggest you to send an email to that address etickets@irctc.co.in

Comment: The above link doesn't work for me. Can you please re-check.
Your comment of all other bookings will be cancelled conflicts with the 2nd point in my answer above? If you have partial confirmation, the confirmed tickets are not cancelled.

Comment: The link worked this time. It is for current booking which allows to book after the final chart has been prepared. Rules for current booking are different from rules for advance booking.

Comment: -1 This is factually incorrect. "if you have a not confirmed pax in your reservation , all other bookings will be cancelled" is not how Indian Railway reservation works. Please see other answers which correctly point out the rules in OP's case.