# Travelling against waitlisted-RAC e-ticket on Indian railway

Tags: tickets, indian-railways

I have 1 [Reservation Against Cancellation (RAC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservation_against_Cancellation) and 2 waitlisted e-tickets for my travel with Indian railways. Can I travel with my family using those?

Comment: Welcome to Travel SE. You have not indicated what is your class of travel. Is it Sleeper, 3-AC or 2-AC? Are all these separate tickets or just different passengers on the same PNR? Waitlisted passengers are not allowed in reserved classes but this rule is generally not observed for sleeper class.

Comment: Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61189/what-will-happen-if-2-out-of-3-seats-are-confirmed-and-1-seat-is-in-waitlist-whi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What will happen if 2 out of 3 seats are confirmed and 1 seat is in Waitlist which is booked via IRCTC online?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61189/what-will-happen-if-2-out-of-3-seats-are-confirmed-and-1-seat-is-in-waitlist-whi)

Comment: @jpatokal Not a duplicate in strictest sense because that question is about confirmed ticket. This question is about RAC. RAC is _not_ a confirmed ticket as per Indian rail.

Comment: @RedBaron But per the other answer, since the RAC holder is allowed to board, the WL holders in the same reservation are also allowed, no?

Comment: @jpatokal It is true that the names of all such passengers will be there on the chart and their tickets are not automatically cancelled. But we don't know the class here (The other question is SL) and we don't know if all these passengers have same PNR or different tickets. For this reason I've voted this as unclear.

Answer (score 3):

As you have not mentioned, there are two possible scenarios here:

**1. All three tickets are on same PNR**

In this case, you are entitled to travel. Other two are "elevated" to RAC status. If you get a birth, three people can share it. This [link from IRCTC](https://www.services.irctc.co.in/beta_htmls/Waitlisted_E-Ticket.html) explicitly state that

An additional facility of booking waitlist e-tickets is now available for all trains. The salient features are as under :-

> Name of the passengers whose status is fully confirmed / fully RAC
>   after chart preparation, their names shall appear in charts & they can
>   undertake their journey. Name of the passengers whose names are partly
>   confirmed/partly waitlist or partly RAC/partly waitlist, their names
>   shall appear in charts including the waitlist passengers.

Same thing is mentioned on the E-Ticket as well:

> 7. PNRs having fully waitlisted status will be dropped and the names of the passengers will not appear on the chart. They are not allowed
>      to board the train. However the namesof PARTIALLY waitlisted/confirmed
>      and RAC will appear in the chart.

As names of all three passengers will appear on chart, you can take the journey. Also, IRCTC automatically cancels the ticket and refunds amount if your ticket remains waitlisted. In this case, they will not do so as one passenger is RAC. So, you have fully paid ticket with which you can board the train but getting a berth depends on TTE.

If you wish to cancel this partial ticket, you will also get the full refund. It is mentioned on E-ticket:

> 14. In case, on a party e-ticket or a family e-ticket issued for travel of more than one passenger, some passengers have confirmed
>       reservation and others are on RAC or waiting list, full refund of fare
>       , less clerkage, shall be admissible for confirmed passengers also
>       subject to the condition that the ticket shall be cancelled online or
>       online TDR shall be filed for all the passengers upto thirty minutes
>       before the scheduled departure of the train.

**2. All three tickets have different PNRs.**

In this case, person with RAC can only travel. Other two tickets will be automatically cancelled and you will get refund. As they have different PNRs, they are simply, different tickets and IRCTC will not know that you are from same family and travelling together.